# .NET Framework 4.8 Error referencing Microsoft.Office.Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-office, office-interop

Im trying to build an old project on a new version of the .NET Framework. When I'm trying to build that Project an Error occurs.

"The file or assembly "Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core" or a dependency of it was not found. An attempt was made to load a file with an incorrect format."

```
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core
 (Partial.)
WRN: Partial binding information was provided for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly name: Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core | Domain ID: 2
WRN: Partial binding occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This may cause the collection folder to load an incorrect assembly.
WRN: Specify the text identity of the assembly with full details. 
WRN: This includes the simple name, version and culture, and public key token.
WRN: For more information and general solutions to this problem, see the whitepaper at "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270".
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/krebesli/OneDrive - TRUMPF SE + Co. KG/Project - Copy/TruTopsSales/TruTopsSales/
LOG: Original PrivatePath = C:\Users/krebesli/OneDrive - TRUMPF SE + Co. KG\Project - copy\TruTopsSales\TruTopsSales\bin
Call from Assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This binding starts in default load context.
LOG: The application configuration file is used: C:\Users\krebesli\OneDrive - TRUMPF SE + Co. KG\Project - copy\TruTopsSales\TruTopsSales\web.config.
LOG: The host configuration file is used: \srvditz1\home$\krebesli\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config.
LOG: The computer configuration file of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config is used.
LOG: policy is not currently applied to the reference (private, custom, partial, or path-based assembly binding).
LOG: download of new URL file:///C:/Users/(username)/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/2636e7dd/88283cb5/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.DLL.
LOG: Download of new URL file:///C:/Users/(username)/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/2636e7dd/88283cb5/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.DLL.
LOG: Download from new URL file:///C:/Users/(username)/.../.../.../bin/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.DLL.
ERR: Assembly setup could not be completed (hr = 0x8007000b). The search was terminated.
```

[Error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01suk.png)

I reference this dll's

[dll's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqMSk.png)

I also add them via the (I believe) correct workflow via the reference managers COM Tab

[COM Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQkg0.png)

- The Microsoft.Office.Core reference adds via the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference adds via the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference adds via the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library

Has anyone a clue what I do wrong?
I tried now evrything and didnt come to an solution

UPDATE:

NuGet installed packages
[NuGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9GGy.png)

Comment: Oh god don't start Office in response to web requests, are you trying to DDoS yourself?

Comment: It's much easier now to use the Office NuGet packages rather than trying to use the old COM stuff. Are you using SDK-style projects?

Comment: @Blindy it's an old project, didn't write it myself

Comment: NuGet packages are Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tried to implement the NuGet packages as you say. But the Error still occurs

Comment: @MatthewWatson I updated the original post

Comment: Do you develop a web application? Is it an ASP.NET or service app?

Comment: @Linus_20 you can't just add an interop package. That interop package interoperates with an *existing Word or Excel application*. You'll have to install Word and Excel on the server and then PAY A LICENSE FOR EVERY POSSIBLE CLIENT whether anonymous or not. So don't

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev it's an ASP.NET

Comment: Having established that you can't do what you try to do, no matter how old the project is, and your company were breaking Microsoft licensing all along, you need to use the correct solution. If you want to create Excel files it's trivial using libraries like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI and more. The `xlsx` format is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML documents. You can manipulate the files yourself but libraries allow you to load an entire table with eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection1 or `LoadFromDataTable`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't develop the project myself. It's just an intern tool. It also works on another pc but not on mine because I try to run it on newer versions of .NET and visual studio. I'm just trying to make it run on a newer plattform

Comment: I already explained why that's a bad idea and what you need to cover this up (install Word or Excel). That won't fix the problem and will still eat a ton of RAM. What are you trying to do? Forget how some old developer tried to hack things. What's the actual requirement? Generate word documents? Excel sheets? Modify user uploaded docs?

Comment: @Linus_20 you need to choose another  strategy instead of automating Office applications from ASP.NET. See my answer for more information on that.

Comment: Whatever the actual problem is, the way for the last 10-12 years is to *not* use Office Interop. Other languages like Python use the same techniques to generate Excel files on the fly even on Linux, where you simply can't install Excel

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the programm generates Excel sheets

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Word and Excel are installed

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I understand that, but i didnt want to rewerite half of the code. Tried to find an easy solution for this. A way i can work with the old code because it works on an other pc with older versions of .NET etc. 

Thought i could get it working on my machine with minor changes in the code

Comment: The problem isn't VS or the .NET Framework version. 4.8 isn't new. You need to use interop packages/libraries that match your installed office applications. If the project contains hard-coded references they'll have to be removed because they'll conflict with those installed through NuGet

Comment: `minor changes in the code` you'll have to know what that code does and how interop works. On the other hand, generating Excel files the usual way (ie without interop) can take just a couple of lines of code. [Check this ClosedXML tutorial](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Copying-IEnumerable-Collections) which loads data in 5 different ways. In all cases the actual work is done by `ws.Cell(7, 6).Value = people.AsEnumerable();` The library will generate a table and fill it from the data you provide. 1 line

Comment: @Linus_20 As everyone is stating, there is no quick way to get this working! If you really want to modernise it, you're going to have to use something like the official [DocumentFormat.OpenXml nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) to create the documents without relying on interop with Word/Excel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there aren't hard coded references in the code. Its referring the references installed via NuGet i think. 

But i think the project was made to run with a specific office version and im using office 365 on my system. This could be a problem

Comment: @phuzi yeah i realized that. I'm not that into .NET so i thought i could get this working without diving completely into the whole projects code

Comment: First, you need to have MS Office installed on the system. Second, instead of using NuGet packages for interop files you can add references using the Add Reference dialog in VS.

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article says the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using EWS or Graph API if you deal with Exchange accounts (Office 365 for Graph API). Or just consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.